# Add item to a list in a SharePoint hosted app from another SharePoint hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-addin, cross-domain

I have two SharePoint hosted apps - say `SPApp1` and `SPApp2`. `SPApp2` has a list `TestList` in `appweb`(NOT the `hostweb`). I want to add an item to that `TestList` from `SPApp1`. I will click a `button` from `SPApp1` and it will add an item to `TestList` in `SPApp2`. 
First of all, is this even possible? If yes, how might one go about this?

Any suggestions, tips are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: This might be possible, but AFAIK this would break the whole idea behind add-ins (apps) being isolated units

Comment: Thanks Robert for the input. Can you give me an idea how I could achieve this? Thanks!